# UNNotificationPresentationOptions.alert can impact live build

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification

As we know the `UNNotificationPresentationOptions.alert` have been depreciated in iOS 14 onwards. My application is still using this `.alert` option. So If I don't update this to [.banner, .list] then may it impact live build running on iOS 14 or above ?